# Why can't I override SSL ServerTrust for NSURLSessionDataTask in XPC service?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ssl, certificate, nsurlsession

I am trying to perform a HTTPS request within an XPC service using an `NSURLSessionDataTask`. This is failing, and is even expected to fail, as the server is using a TLS certificate signed by a CA unknown to the system.

So I implemented the `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocol, implemented the `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` method, obtained the `SecTrustRef` object, added the certificate of the CA to it (which ships with my XPC service), and evaluated the trust with `SecTrustEvaluate()`. If I evaluate without adding my CA first, the system says the certificate is not trusted, if I do so after adding my CA, the system says it is trusted, so apparently I'm doing everything right. Finally I call

```
NSURLCredential * credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
```

And the connection... still fails. And it still fails with exactly the same error as if I wasn't using that delegate at all (`NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed`). Exactly the same code was working fine in another project. Even when I don't evaluate at all and just implement the method as follows:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
    didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
    completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, 
        NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
{
    NSString * method = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;
    if (![method isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
        return;
    }

    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    if (!serverTrust) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
        return;
    }

    NSURLCredential * credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
}
```

The connection stil fails with the error `NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when *ATS* (App Transport Security) is active, which is the default for all apps linked against the SDKs of iOS 9.0/macOS 11.0 or later, an `NSURLSessionDelegate` **can only tighten** security constraints, e.g. using cert/public key pinning, but it **cannot loosen them** anymore as regardless what the delegate says, ATS will "always do its thing". And aside from forcing the usage of HTTPS instead of HTTP, ATS also performs it own certificate checks.

If you want to perform certificate validation all by yourself, you have to disable ATS. Therefor your `Info.plist` requires a key `NSAppTransportSecurity`, whose value is a dictionary and contains the boolean key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES`.

From the documentation:

> NSURLSession enforces App Transport Security (ATS), if it is enabled for the domain you are connecting to. This applies security requirements for the certificates, TLS version, and cipher used by the connection. **You cannot loosen server trust requirements for an ATS-protected domain**, but you can tighten them, using the manual evaluation technique shown in this article.

Source: [Performing Manual Server Trust Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication?language=objc)

And also:

> Without ATS, you’re also **free to loosen** the default server trust requirements, as described in Performing Manual Server Trust Authentication.

Source: [Property List Key - NSAllowsArbitraryLoads](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads?language=objc)

**Note:**
When disabling ATS for an App Store build, Apple requires a written justification from you as for why your app actually requires that exception, so that Apple